# I have error when use context in adapter, i would like use startActivityForResult(...) in adapter, how should I do?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-adapter, android-context

and thank you in advance for your suggestions.

**MainActivity.java**

```
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
@Override
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);

    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getBaseContext(),TITLES,ICONS,NAME,EMAIL,PROFILE);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);       
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
...}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Bitmap bitmap   = null;
    String path = "";
    mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
    path = getPath(mImageCaptureUri); //from Gallery

    if (path == null)
        path = mImageCaptureUri.getPath();
    if (path != null)
        bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

**Myadapter.java**

```
class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
...
Context mContext;
Activity mActivity;
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
private String selectedImagePath;

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {...}

MyAdapter(Context context, String Titles[],int Icons[],String Name,String Email, int Profile){
    this.mContext = context;
    mNavTitles = Titles
    mIcons = Icons;
    name = Name;
    email = Email;
    profile = Profile;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(holder.Holderid ==1) {                              
        holder.textView.setText(mNavTitles[position - 1]); 
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(mIcons[position -1]);
    }
    else{
        holder.profile.setImageResource(profile);           
        holder.Name.setText(name);
        holder.email.setText(email);
        holder.profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mActivity = (Activity)mContext;
                Intent imageIntent = new Intent();
                imageIntent.setType("image/*");
                imageIntent.setAction(imageIntent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                mActivity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(imageIntent, "Select photo"), 2);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

It's possible call `startActivityForResult` in Adapter?
Why error is on `mActivity = (Activity)mContext;`?

p.s.: I tried to create method
`public void startxx(Intent i){
        startActivityForResult(i, 2);
    }`
and call this in Adapter...but Adapter wants statxx static and Activity non-static.

Comment: What you can do is you can implement listener which you can implement in your adapter. And use listener in onActiviytResult to listen the method triggering.

Answer (score 2):

Context is Base class for Activity. You can not downcast object in Java. Thats why you can not perform `mActivity = (Activity)mContext;`.

You can not call startActivityForResult() from as Adapter class as it is method of Activity.java class. Here is one solution you can try -
- Declare one interface. say IObserver.java

```
public interface IObserver {

    // change signature of method as per your need
    public abstract void onItemClicked();
    }
}
```

- Write one method in Adapter class say

  public void setListener(IObserver obs) {
  mObserver = obs;
  }
- Implement IObserver interface in Activity class. You need to implement onItemClicked() method as well.
- From onCreate() method of activity, call `adapter.setListener(this);`
- In adapter class, from onClick() method, write code as below

> ```
> holder.profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>             @Override 
>             public void onClick(View v) {
>                // It will call method from activity class where you can do startActivityForResult()
>                mObserver.onItemClicked();
>             } 
>         });
> ```

Hope it will help.